# PHP Form not submitting on php despite working on html

Tags: php, html, forms

When I try and submit a form here (php page) - http://portsdownhb.ogdigital.co.uk/ the page throws the error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' when pressing submit, despite the exact same working on a HTML page.

The error suggests the page http://portsdownhb.ogdigital.co.uk/contact-us/contact.php is trying to be found but it should be http://portsdownhb.ogdigital.co.uk/contact.php

```js
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();


    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {

                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

      <div class="messages"></div>

      <div class="controls">

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="****"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: I was able to submit successful (with a false email). Are you really, **really**, sure this question is not a spammy attempt to attract traffic to your site?

Comment: I do apologies, the form works on incognito so appears to be a caching issue. I will delete the question